# Polymer: scrollbar underneath core-scroll-header-panel?

Tags: html, scroll, polymer

As of 2014-10-22, the header part of a core-scroll-header-panel widget is drawn over the top of the browser's scrollbar. This is deeply suboptimal, as it can make the thumb completely inaccessible until you scroll down. (And first you have to notice there's a scroll bar.)

The standard Polymer demo for the widget demonstrates this:

https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-scroll-header-panel/demo.html

This happens in both Chrome and Firefox.

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: There's a couple of bugs upon in regards to scrolling: https://github.com/Polymer/core-scroll-header-panel/issues